# Inner working of this jquery script

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

I have a Jquery Script which is depenedent on this Script Sort.js . Can any body How does this works

```
jQuery.fn.sort = (function(){

    var sort = [].sort;

    return function(comparator, getSortable) {

        getSortable = getSortable || function(){return this;};

        var placements = this.map(function(){

              var sortElement = getSortable.call(this),               
                parentNode = sortElement.parentNode,                      
                // Since the element itself will change position, we have
                // to have some way of storing it's original position in
                // the DOM. The easiest way is to have a 'flag' node:
                nextSibling = parentNode.insertBefore(
                    document.createTextNode(''),
                    sortElement.nextSibling
                );

            return function() {

                if (parentNode === this) {
                    throw new Error(
                        "You can't sort elements if any one is a descendant of another."
                    );
                }

                // Insert before flag:
                parentNode.insertBefore(this, nextSibling);
                // Remove flag:
                parentNode.removeChild(nextSibling);

            };

        });

        return sort.call(this, comparator).each(function(i){
            placements[i].call(getSortable.call(this));
        });

    };

})();
```

I got this Script from this link http://qd9.co.uk/projects/jQuery-Plugins/sort/demo.html

Comment: Can you narrow down your question? It is overly broad. Which part(s) do you not understand?

Comment: @patrick dw: Sorry to say this .Iam not able to understand  any line of code. except that i know it is a closure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It takes essentially three inputs:

- `this` is the jQuery object you are calling it on, e.g. if it was `$("#my-id").sort()` then `this` would be `$("#my-id")`
- `comparator` is a comparison function of the same type as accepted by [JavaScript's native `Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)
- `getSortable` is an optional transformation function that is applied to the sorted DOM elements before they are actually sorted. Its behavior is a bit confusing to me still; it appears it would only work if it returned another DOM element?

It gets the `Array.prototype.sort` method via the line

```
var sort = [].sort;
```

It then uses it with the `comparator` function to get a sorted version of the jQuery object, which is "array-like" since it has properties `0`, `1`, `2`, ... and a `length` property:

```
sort.call(this, comparator)
```

It then loops through the result, calling `placements[i]` on either the DOM element itself (default) or whatever `getSortable` returns when given a DOM element:

```
sort.call(this, comparator).each(function(i){
        placements[i].call(getSortable.call(this));
    });
```

So the real magic happens in the creation of the `placements` array. After some thought, we see that `placements[i]` is a function that inserts its input into the same place that the `i`th element of `this` was, *before* sorting happened. So calling `placement[i]` using the `i`th *sorted* element as input results in placing the `i`th *sorted* element in the `i`th "slot", i.e. the place where the `i`th *unsorted* element was. The whole business with "flag" nodes inside the `placements` array creation is so that it can track the position of the original "slots" even after you start replacing them with new, sorted elements.

Also worth noting: it (rather unnecessarily IMO) wraps itself in an immediately-executing anonymous function which itself returns a function taking the `comparator` and `getSortable` parameters. Thus the actual result assigned to `jQuery.fn.sort` is the two-parameter function.